# Opencv car counting

Tags: java, opencv

hi guys today i got a little problem about cars counting in opencv using java. i perfectly detect cars on video but my car counter didn't count perfectly for example if we have 10 cars it counts only 8 sometimes 9. this is my final year project please help me. here is my code about detection of cars

```
    while (running) {
        Mat previusFrame = new Mat();
        Mat currentFrame = new Mat();
        Mat grayImage1 = new Mat();
        Mat grayImage2 = new Mat();
        Mat differenceImage = new Mat();
        Mat thresholdImage = new Mat();

        camera.read(previusFrame);
        Imgproc.resize(previusFrame, previusFrame, new Size(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        Imgproc.cvtColor(previusFrame, grayImage1, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        while (running) {
            boolean frameSucces = camera.read(currentFrame);
            if (frameSucces) {
                Imgproc.resize(currentFrame, currentFrame, new Size(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
                Imgproc.cvtColor(currentFrame, grayImage2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

            } else {
                break;
            }

            //abbs differnce
            Core.absdiff(grayImage1, grayImage2, differenceImage);
            Imgproc.threshold(differenceImage, thresholdImage, SENSITIVE, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
            Imgproc.blur(thresholdImage, thresholdImage, new Size(BLUR, BLUR));
            Imgproc.threshold(thresholdImage, thresholdImage, SENSITIVE, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

            //finding Movement
            Mat heirarchy = new Mat();
            Rect boundingRect = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            List<MatOfPoint> contour = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
            Imgproc.findContours(thresholdImage, contour, heirarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            for (int i = 0; i < contour.size(); i++) {
                boundingRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour.get(i));

                if (boundingRect.area() > 500) {
                    Imgproc.rectangle(currentFrame, boundingRect.tl(), boundingRect.br(), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);

                }
            }
            Imgproc.line(currentFrame, new Point(10, 200), new Point(currentFrame.width() - 10, 200), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);

            Moments moment = Imgproc.moments(thresholdImage);
            double m10 = moment.get_m10();
            double m01 = moment.get_m01();
            double m_area = moment.get_m00();
            int posx = (int) (m10 / m_area);
            int posy = (int) (m01 / m_area);
            if (posy > 202 && posy <= 245) {
                i++;
            }
            label.setText("cars Number" + i);
            MatOfByte matof = new MatOfByte();
            Imgcodecs.imencode(".bmp", currentFrame, matof);
            byte[] data = matof.toArray();
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MotionDetecter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            Graphics g = getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 20, null);

            grayImage2.copyTo(grayImage1);

        }

        camera.release();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MotionDetecter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "I perfectly detect cars on video", do you mean you draw 10 rectangles around the cars? If so, why not count the cars at the same time as drawing the rectangle? If not, do you really detect the cars perfectly?

Comment: yes i can detect cars...thank you andy

Comment: But what I'm trying to understand is *how you know that you can detect cars*. What are you doing that convinces you that you detect 10 cars? And "perfectly" at that? (I'm not trolling, I am trying to understand the problem)

Comment: every time when the cars move it draws a bounding rectangle on each cars..what i wnat to know is when the cars pass the crossing line how i can increment counting values...sorry for my english

Comment: Is there only one car in the frame at once? I am puzzled because you seem to be detecting cars based on the area of contours detected in the image; but then you are incrementing a counter based on moments of the image. It seems like the rectangle and counter should be based on the same thing.

Comment: no there coud be many cars..do you have any advice how i can implement without movement

Comment: Depending upon how fast the cars are moving, you can use the overlap of contours between frames as a way to say "this car in frame (N) is the same car as that car in frame (N+1)".

Comment: use some real tracking like TLD or particle filtering. once done you can easily compute whether the trajectory crosses your virtual loop detector line...